# Document Viewer (evince) not opening from terminal

Tags: 18.04, pdf, evince

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Whenever I try to open evince from the command line:

```
> evince something.pdf
```

I get this error (even without a pdf file):

```
evince: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Oddly, I can open it using nautilus with no problems. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Probably it happens because you run the command as _root_

Comment: Ready to break your system in that case. Fortunatelly, the system protected you in this, but usually, it doesn't because it assumes that you know what you are doing if you act as administrator.

Comment: @mook765, I'm not running as root. Sorry, the '#' is misleading. I was running this as a regular user. I have edited it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. Running

```
ldd $(which evince)
```

output this:

```
... 
liblz4.so.1 => /home/USER/root-build/build/lib/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f15f8ea0000)
```

Which led me to discover that my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set to

```
/home/USER/root-build/build/lib
```

from a script I call in my .bashrc to set up an analysis package I use. Removing the line calling the script resolved the issue.

Comment: I have similar error, but `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty and I can't understand how to fix this error